# How to Remove WPF ScrollViewer Border

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, scrollviewer

In the WPF application I'm developing, every ScrollViewer control puts a white border around the content it's displaying, and I need this border removed. The border is present with and without my custom styles.
The only time it doesn't show is when I enable AllowTransparency for my window, but AllowTransparency must remain disabled - the window is borderless with no chrome, and the way I'm applying a necessary drop shadow requires AllowTransparency to be false.

What it looks like:
[image]

Here is a closeup of the top-right corner:
[image]

That obnoxious white border ruins the look of my application, and needs to go. I don't believe it is the background of another element showing through, as I've set just about every parent element's background to non-white or transparent colors and it still shows. How can I remove the offending border while keeping AllowTransparency disabled and retaining my chrome-less window?

Code for clarification: This UserControl contains an afflicted ScrollViewer: [hastebin.com/okudoyubal.xml](http://hastebin.com/okudoyubal.xml) and is a child in this UserControl: [hastebin.com/esiregapem.xml](http://hastebin.com/esiregapem.xml) 
Using slightly modified Metro theme: http://www.mediafire.com/file/xjawcacw3gzk435/ModMetroTheme.zip 
and here are the specific ScrollViewer styles: https://hastebin.com/uvulihekex.xml

Comment: What is the content of the `ScrollViewer`?  What is the `ScrollViewer` Background property set to?  Can you create a very simple XAML page that demonstrates the problem and post that Xaml code.  I created a simple Window with a `Grid` into which I placed a `ScrollViewer`.  The only properties I set on the `ScrollViewer` were to set a Margin of 10 and a Background of LightBlue.  I then placed a `Canvas` inside the 'ScrollViewer'.  I don't see any white border on my Window.

Comment: This UserControl contains an afflicted ScrollViewer: https://hastebin.com/okudoyubal.xml and is a child in this UserControl: https://hastebin.com/esiregapem.xml

Comment: I copied your code and see no white border, but the scrollbar looks different as well. Have you applied any style here? Can you also post it, maybe it is what causing a border.

Comment: I'm using a slightly modified Metro-like theme for select components: http://www.mediafire.com/file/xjawcacw3gzk435/ModMetroTheme.zip, and here's the ScrollViewer specific styles: https://hastebin.com/uvulihekex.xml Oddly enough, however, the white border appears with both the Metro ScrollViewers and the default Win 7 ScrollViewers

Comment: I'm with lena, I copied your code and I don't see any white border. Your blur hack seems completely wrong to me. You have some style that is introducing that border. Find it and fix it correctly, not with a blur.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Sir, I am aware of my odd workaround. That's is why I called it a **workaround**. I am also aware that this is likely a styling problem. But when a problem has persisted for weeks (take one second to look at the dates on this question), and one has spent hours upon hours searching for solutions, it is completely acceptable to implement a workaround so that main development can continue once more; then, later on, a proper solution can be researched under better conditions. Your gruff comment has done nothing to help, but something to antagonize me.

Comment: Do you have VS2015? Look at the live visual tree tool to see where its coming from?

Comment: @SledgeHammer Yeah, I did some poking around with that but didn't get very far: https://s24.postimg.org/72ww0dvlh/resuktlst.png         I dug through my styles for quite some time, trying to find anything associated with the ScrollViewer and grid that had strokethickness, a border, a margin, etc.

Comment: If clearing the border fixed the one side, you are 25% of the way there. What I usually do is start working at the top of the visual tree and set obvious backgrounds (I.e. red, blue, etc) to see which one shows through. It sounds like something is overriding the scrollviewer style which is why your fix worked. If you use the real scrollviewer style dumped from Blend, do you still have the border?

Comment: @SledgeHammer If you're talking about the default Win7-style ScrollViewer then yes, the border shows when I disable my custom ScrollViewer styles _but_ while keep all other custom styles enabled. That is, if I enable all custom styles except for ScrollViewer, ScrollBar, ScrollBarButtonStyle, etc. so that those elements alone reflect the Win7 style, the border still shows. This has led me to suspect the ContentPresenter or Grid elements/styles, but I didn't find any margin, border, etc. that caused change upon its removal. I believe the border exists due to UI changes made by .NET on app launch

Comment: The default win7 scroll viewer doesn't have the border, so you are overriding it somewhere. Don't disable the style but flat out copy the default one in and force it. You'll see no border. Also try a stock app with no custom styles to prove it.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Yeah, the border wont be there in a clean slate app; something in the custom styles is likely acting odd. I want to keep my custom ScrollViewer style, however, so I'll continue to periodically dig at this issue and hopefully find the root culprit.

Answer (score 2):

It could be vary by controls, but I could achieve with `BorderThinkness="0"` in `ScrollViewer` contained contol.

Note: I wrote this answer because this approach seems not tried. The op's `hastbin.com` links are not accessible now.

Answer (score 0):

I've learned some more and found a workaround. The white border between cells is the ScrollViewer's grid's background showing through. Or rather, the lack of a background. While it's set to be transparent, it decides to act non-transparent instead, which can be cheaply solved by changing the grid's background color. However, this is klutzy to do, as either every ScrollViewer and other Grid-using elements now have that solid background, or each one must be set manually (potentially ruining grids for which the cell border doesn't show anyways).

While the following workaround does not work in every place in my application, it works in some:

```
<Style x:Key="ScrollViewerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid Background="{x:Null}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" UseLayoutRounding="True">
                    <Grid.Effect>
                        <BlurEffect KernelType="Box" Radius="0"/>
                    </Grid.Effect>

                    // Content

                </Grid>
            ...
```

Setting the background to transparent, snapping to pixels, using layout rounding, **and** applying the box blur of 0 removes the see-through margins between cells. Additionally, there is no noticeable performance loss from the effect - as far as I can tell.

Perhaps the blur effect inherently requires transparency, and its introduction tricks the confused Grid into actually having a transparent cell border.

---

If anyone has a solution to removing this cell border altogether, that'd still be very great to hear!